# How can I have jQuery calculation results display based on default selections

Tags: jquery, html

I use the code below to calculate value of business cards based on the user's selection. The user customize options using radio buttons, the values of the checked radio buttons is then used to calculate the net price, vat and total price. These values are then displayed in a div. There are radio buttons selected by default however the prices only start showing once the user click on one of the radio buttons. Since there are default options selected, how can I have the prices corresponding to these option display when the page load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[form="businessCards"]').click(function() {


    var totalNetPrice = designLayoutPrice + printRunPrice + printedSidesPrice + paperWeightPrice + refiningPrice + processingPrice + deliveryMethodPrice;
    $(".totalNetPrice").html(totalNetPrice.toFixed(2));

    var vat = totalNetPrice * 0.14;
    $(".vat").html(vat.toFixed(2));

    var totalPrice = totalNetPrice + vat;
    $(".totalPrice").html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));

  });   

});
```

I tried adding adding the following but does work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // display default option values
  $(".totalNetPrice").html.(totalNetPrice); 
  $(".vat").html.(vat);
  $(".totalPrice").html.(totalPrice);

  $('input[form="businessCards"]').click(function() {


    var totalNetPrice = designLayoutPrice + printRunPrice + printedSidesPrice + paperWeightPrice + refiningPrice + processingPrice + deliveryMethodPrice;
    $(".totalNetPrice").html(totalNetPrice.toFixed(2));

    var vat = totalNetPrice * 0.14;
    $(".vat").html(vat.toFixed(2));

    var totalPrice = totalNetPrice + vat;
    $(".totalPrice").html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));

  });   

});
```

Comment: Can you show us the html, so it's easier to debug? Also `.html.(totalPrice)`  and `.html.(totalNetPrice)` - I think you want it without the dot in the middle, i.e. `.html(totalPrice)`  and `.html(totalNetPrice)`.

Comment: can you try calling `$('input[form="businessCards"]').trigger("click");` at the bottom of your code inside `$(documnet).ready`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can trigger the click event manually so the price will be computed with default values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[form="businessCards"]').click(function() {


    var totalNetPrice = designLayoutPrice + printRunPrice + printedSidesPrice + paperWeightPrice + refiningPrice + processingPrice + deliveryMethodPrice;
    $(".totalNetPrice").html(totalNetPrice.toFixed(2));

    var vat = totalNetPrice * 0.14;
    $(".vat").html(vat.toFixed(2));

    var totalPrice = totalNetPrice + vat;
    $(".totalPrice").html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));

  }).click(); // trigger event

});
```

Comment: This solution should work fine. You can also create a function which computes total price with the steps inside the click function and can call it `onClick` and on document load.

Comment: I have created the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/imonareng/DTcHh/23529/). If I trigger the click event manually as suggested, the default option now becomes the last option under each option category. The total value of the default option is supposed to be R1162.80. When I add .click(), the total value now becomes R2086.20 and all last option are now checked.

Comment: I managed to get it fixed. I added $('input[form="businessCards"]:checked').trigger("click"); at the bottom code as suggested by @vijayP